# Debugging unexpected errors in R -- how can I find where the error occurred?

Tags: r, error-handling, r-faq

Sometimes R throws me errors such as

> Error in if (ncol(x) != 2) { : argument is of length zero

with no additional information, when I've written no such code. Is there a general way for finding which function in which package causes an error?

Since most packages come compressed, it isn't trivial to grep `/usr/lib/R/library`.

Comment: I find the easiest way to debug is to step through the code line by line.  If your error is coming from a function you wrote, you can debug it using `debugonce(function_name)`.  This will give you a mini R session inside the scope of the function.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but I feel like I spend too much time on something that could be automated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `traceback()` to locate where the last error occurred. Usually it will point you to a call you make in your function. Then I typically put `browser()` at that point, run the function again and see what is going wrong.

For example, here are two functions:

```
f2 <- function(x)
{
  if (x==1) "foo"
}

f <- function(x)
{
  f2(x)
}
```

Note that `f2()` assumes an argument of length `1`. We can misuse `f`:

```
> f(NULL)
Error in if (x == 1) "foo" : argument is of length zero
```

Now we can use `traceback()` to locate what went wrong:

```
> traceback()
2: f2(x) at #3
1: f(NULL)
```

The number means how deep we are in the nested functions. So we see that `f` calls `f2` and that gives an error at line `3`. Pretty clear. We could reassign `f` with `browser` placed just before the `f2` call now to check it's input. `browser()` simply allows you to stop executing a function and look around in its environment. Similar to `debug` and `debugonce` except that you don't have to execute every line up until the point you know something goes wrong.

Comment: Nitpick: It's not `f2` assuming the argument is of length >0, it's the `if` statement.

Answer (score 19):

Just to add to what @SachaEpskamp has already suggested, setting `options(error=recover)` and `options(show.error.locations=TRUE)` can be extremely helpful when debugging unfamiliar code. The first causes R to launch a debugging session on error, giving you the option to invoke the browser at any point in the call stack up to that error. The second option will tell R to include the source line number in the error.

Comment: additionally, if you set `options(warn=2)` then the same will occur upon a warning, which can be useful if you end up having factors converted to numbers incorrectly (inducing `NA`, which is typically not what you want

Comment: So set my options to options(error=recover), options(show.error.locations=TRUE), and options(warn=2), but would like to reset these options to their original state. How would I do that?

Comment: `o <- options(error=recover, show.error.locations=TRUE, warn=2);#do stuff;do.call(options, o) # reset` Feel free to upvote if this answer helped you.